# Creating an Instance of a Class Returns Warning?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm learning about classes in Objective-C. I have created a class called "CurrencyConverter".

According to my knowledge, there's more than one way to create an instance of this class in another file. So in my AppDelegate.h, I created an instance using the variable type "id" like so:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{

id currencyConverter;

}
```

So in my AppDelegate.m I can declare it like so without any warning:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

// Override point for customization after application launch.

currencyConverter = [[CurrencyConverter alloc] init];

return YES;

}
```

However, when I create an instance of my class like the following, I get a warning saying "Unused variable:myCC"

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

// Override point for customization after application launch.

CurrencyConverter *myCC = [[CurrencyConverter alloc] init];

return YES;

}
```

Note that I did not create an instance of "myCC" in the Appdelegate.h, I only did that for "currencyConverter". Also take note that I did

```
#import "CurrencyConverter.h"
```

At the top of my Appdelegate.m

So my question is how come one method of creating an instance of a class doesn't have a warning, and the other one does? Aren't they both technically unused?...

Comment: Please, please, please learn how to program before you start with Objective-C!!!  You've got some serious misconceptions here!  Objective-C is not a beginner's language!

Comment: `id currencyConverter;` does not create an "instance".  `currencyConverter = [[CurrencyConverter alloc] init];` is not a declaration.

Comment: Sorry, i guess I don't have the names of things down yet. But hey, can't blame me for trying to be self-taught :/

Comment: You clearly do not have a grasp of the basic concepts of pointers and object-oriented programming.  Until you do, all you will learn is bad habits if you continue with Objective-C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CurrencyConverter *myCC = [[CurrencyConverter alloc] init];
return YES;
```

The variable `myCC` in the above is a *local* variable. It lives only as long as this method. But the method ends in the next line with no further mention of `myCC`, so creating it was pointless; it comes into existence and vanishes again (and so does this CurrencyConverter).

(In the other code, `myCC` is an *instance* variable, so its value - a different CurrencyConverter - persists after being created and assigned to it. In any case the Objective-C compiler will never complain about an unused instance variable, as that notion means nothing.)

Comment: So "currencyConverter" is a variable that I can use all throughout that file and in various methods in that file, because I created an instance of it in my .h?

Comment: Not because you created it in your _.h_. Because you declared it as an instance variable. You can do that in your _.h_ or in your _.m_. An instance variable is global to all methods of that instance; that is part of what it is to be an instance variable.

Comment: Even more important is that it _persists_, as I said in my answer. Local variables are "automatic" - they (and their values) vanish in a puff of smoke when their scope ends (e.g. the method in which they are declared). Instance variables have the same lifetime as the instance itself.

Comment: Thus, the compiler will never call an instance variable unused, because it persists. It might be used by code elsewhere. But it is easy for the compiler to see when a local variable is unused, so it warns. You can turn off the warning, but don't.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about the stack and the heap, and local variables vs. instance variables.

When you call a method, the variables declared between it's "{" and "}" brackets are LOCAL variables. They only exist for the life of the method. Those variables are declared on the "stack".

Think of the stack as a stack of sheets of note paper. When you call a method, the processor puts down a new blank piece of paper on the stack, and uses that piece of paper to store all the local variables from your method. When you get to the closing brace (the "}") the method returns, and the processor takes that method's sheet of paper off the stack and throws it away. Any information on that sheet of paper is lost.

Actually, any time you use an opening brace, the compiler slaps down a new blank sheet of paper, and any variables you declare are added to the new, blank sheet of paper. When you get to the matching closing brace, the top sheet of paper is thrown away, and any variables that were declared between the inner-most opening and closing braces is discarded. A set of braces defines a "local scope". Any variables declared inside those braces are only visible inside the braces, and only EXIST inside the braces. As soon as the program exits the closing brace, all variables defined between the opening and closing brace are discarded.

The stack is like that, but computer memory. The stack is more like a stack of empty storage cubbies. When the computer first starts, all the cubbies are empty. There is a "stack pointer" that points to the first empty cubby (memory location) at the top of the stack. If you push something onto the stack, it gets stored into the empty cubby, and the stack pointer gets moved up to the next empty cubby. If you pop something off the stack, it gets taken out of the first non-empty cubby at the top of the stack and the stack pointer drops down to point to the now-empty cubby. When you return from a method or exiting a set of braces, the compiler remembers how much stack space you used, and pops everything you stored off the stack and throws it away.

Instance variables are different. They are stored in the heap, which is a block of memory that is kept around for the life of your program. When you create an object, the processor carves a block of memory out of the heap big enough for your object and hands you a pointer to that memory. You then initialize your object, which sets up the memory in it's "clean" starting state. If you release an object, that bit of heap memory gets freed up. Storage space in the heap is not top-to-bottom. It's more like first-come, first-served. If you create 10 objects, then free 4 of them, there will be holes in the stack memory where those 4 objects used to be. Heap space is more like tables in a restaurant. If you ask for a block of memory, the OS looks for a free block of memory on the heap large enough (or larger than) the size you asked for, much like a restaurant seats groups of people at the smallest table that's big enough to seat the whole group, even if the table is slightly bigger than the group.